# How to secure an application under iOS against jailbroken devices

Tags: appsec, mobile, ios

I noticed that some apps, e.g. Skype, is capable to exit and not run in case one has jailbroken his iOS based device.

1. I couldn't find online how to check that a device is jailbroken. Please anyhelp from the IT Security community?
2. Is there other means, other than just closing the app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You have two problems (or more).

   - Firstly, anything you might try to do to detect a jailbroken system could be interpreted by Apple as an attempt by your app to violate the sandboxing conditions, which could lead to your app being rejected. For example, let's say you tried to detect a jailbroken OS by `if (-1 != open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY))`. Apple might assume you're trying to read from `/dev/random` and reject you.
   - Anything you might try to do to detect a jailbroken system could be patched by the jailbreak community. For example, they might patch their kernel to forbid your app from opening `/dev/random`, because they know you're only doing it to detect a jailbroken OS.
2. What else would you want to do? You don't trust the OS you're running on, so you give up running on it.

In short, jailbreaking is not your problem, it is Apple's problem. Allow Apple to solve their problems and concentrate on solving yours. (Incidentally I do wonder how people ever released PC software if they don't trust jailbroken iOS, when Windows and jailbroken iOS basically allow the same things to happen.)

Comment: point 2 is true, I do distrust jailbroken iOS! I either disallow storage on the iOS or I should find a way to secure it more than just the keychain! --thanks anyway

Comment: Yes, if an operating system was vulnerable to user tinkering, no company would write software for it.

Comment: My point exactly: all pc operating systems can be thus tinkered with, and yet software vendors still write for them.